# Get values from only the related parents when matching a child

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to get a value from an array by matching a value in a child array, but everything I try either returns nothing or all of members of the parent array. I only want the info from the parent where the child matches.

Specifically, I want to list all of the AWS security groups that have port 22 rules in them.

This is a reduced sample output from the aws command line that I am trying to parse:

```
{
    "SecurityGroups": [
        {
            "Description": "ssh and web group",
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "FromPort": 22,
                    "ToPort": 22
                },
                {
                    "FromPort": 80,
                    "ToPort": 80
                }
            ],
            "GroupName": "ssh-web",
            "GroupId": "sg-11111111"
        },
        {
            "Description": "https group",
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "FromPort": 443,
                    "ToPort": 443
                },
                {
                    "FromPort": 8443,
                    "ToPort": 8443
                }
            ],
            "GroupName": "https",
            "GroupId": "sg-22222222"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried this:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups |
    jq '.SecurityGroups[] as $top |
        .SecurityGroups[].IpPermissions[] |
        select(.FromPort == 22) |
        $top'
```

and this:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups |
    jq '. as $top |
        .SecurityGroups[].IpPermissions[] |
        select(.FromPort == 22) |
        $top'
```

Both commands show both of the top-level array entries instead of just one containing the port 22 entry; they just show the entire output from the aws command.

The person who answered this question below specifically refers to the potential scoping problem that I am actually having, but his brief description of how to deal with it isn't enough for me to understand:

[jq - How do I print a parent value of an object when I am already deep into the object's children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689645/jq-how-do-i-print-a-parent-value-of-an-object-when-i-am-already-deep-into-the)

I want to see this:

```
GroupName: "https"
GroupID: "sg-22222222"
```

I don't think I fully understand how using 'as' works, which may be my stumbling block.

Comment: I should have been more careful about accepting those edits. They messed up the format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't descend into children if you need parent.

```
.SecurityGroups[]
| select(any(.IpPermissions[]; .FromPort == 22))
| .GroupName, .GroupId
```

should work.

Comment: That definitely works! Thanks! I am still trying to wrap my head around the use of 'any' and what a generator is.

Comment: Now that I see the mistake of descending, is there a reason to not do just this? 

```jq  -r '.SecurityGroups[] | select(.IpPermissions[].FromPort == 22) | .GroupName, .GroupId'```

Comment: @bchill isn't it obvious? `.IpPermissions[]` **generates** a stream of port rules, and if **any** of them contains `FromPort: 22` the parent is selected.

Comment: @bchill yes there is. if there are two port rules containing `FromPort: 22`, the parent is selected twice.

Comment: Ahhh. Got it. I was able to produce an example of superfluous results. Thanks!